# itgensdf054 on synchronize in Invantive Control

Tags: excel, exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

When synchronizing a model in Excel with one block, I receive an itgensdf054 error which indicates that it could not clear the target range where the data of the query below is synchronized into.

The full error message is:

> Could not clear contents of the range ''Aangifte Bebat'!$A$6:$Q$129' of block 'ECO'.
>   Deze wijziging kan niet worden doorgevoerd voor de geselecteerde cellen omdat ze van invloed zijn op een draaitabel. Gebruik de lijst  met velden om het rapport te wijzigen. Verplaats de draaitabel en probeer het opnieuw als u cellen wilt invoegen of verwijderen

Call stack:

```
Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   bij System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   bij Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.ClearContents()
   bij Invantive.Producer.Control.SyncToDatabaseForm.SyncDownload(DoWorkEventArgs e) in File176:regel 1508
   bij Invantive.Producer.Control.SyncToDatabaseForm.SyncDownload(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   bij Invantive.Producer.Control.SyncToDatabaseForm.syncBackGroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   bij System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

The block 'ECO' synchronizes data from the following query on Exact Online:

```
select /*+ join_set(sik, invoiceid, 100) join_set(sil, invoiceid, 100) join_set(itm, id, 100) join_set(itr, id, 100) */sil.itemcode
,      sil.description
,      bom.batchquantity
,      sil.quantity
,      sil.netprice
,      sil.amountdc
,      sil.vatamountdc
,      sil.vatcode
,      sil.vatcodedescription
,      sil.vatpercentage
,      sik.invoicenumber
,      sil.linenumber
,      itr.itemgroupcode
,      itm.class_04  --aanpassen naar inrichting klant = assortiment bebat_nomenclatuur
,      itm.class_10  -- is assortiment 10 instellingen stuklijst explosie
,      case
       when sik.invoicenumber is not null
       then '=if($C{D,.,.,.-5,.}=$C{D,.,.,.-5,.-1}, if($C{D,.,.,^+2,.}= "", $C{D,.,.,^,.-1}, $C{D,.,.,^,.}), $C{D,.,.,^,.})'
       end
       ass_itemcode
,      case
       when sik.invoicenumber is not null
       /*=""&ALS(K6=K5;ALS(C6<>"";N6;N5);N6)*/
       then '="" & if($C{D,.,.,.-6,.}=$C{D,.,.,.-6,.-1}, if($C{D,.,.,^+2,.} <> "", $C{D,.,.,.-3,.}, $C{D,.,.,.-3,.-1}), $C{D,.,.,.-3,.})'
       end
       nomenclatuur
from   ExactOnlineREST..SalesInvoiceLines sil
join   ExactOnlineREST..SalesInvoices sik
on     sil.invoiceid = sik.invoiceid
join   ExactOnlineREST..Items itm
on     sil.item = itm.id
join   ExactOnlineREST..ItemsRead itr
on     sil.item = itr.id
left
outer 
join   ExactOnlineXML..BillOfMaterials bom
on     sil.itemcode =  bom.item_code_attr 
order 
by     sik.invoicenumber
,      sil.linenumber
```

The query or the model has not changed when it worked before.

There is a pivot table in the Excel sheet which summarizes the list of sales details.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Does the range 'Aangifte Bebat'!$A$6:$Q$129' contain the data downloaded?

Comment: THe range Aangifte Bebat contains the pivot table. The data is in Details worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I understand that the pivot table is in 'Aangifte Bebat' worksheet, but the downloaded is in 'Details' worksheet.

I think you have made a slight alteration. Probably you have inserted or moved a new worksheet BEFORE the Details worksheet. Since Invantive Control downloads based upon the number of the worksheet, the data has now been moved.

Make sure that the original order of worksheets is restored.